# python selenium webdriver - an alternative in urlib2

Tags: python, selenium, urllib2, basic-authentication

Dear All StackOberflow Users,
I wrote simple script that opens webpage in IE and then enters the username and password, hereunder is my example:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    import time

    driver = webdriver.Ie('C:\IEDriverServer.exe')
    driver.get("my_url")

    driver.switch_to.alert.authenticate("k jastrzebski","pass")
```

I works well, but it requires IE to has Enabled Protected Mode. My url needs to have disabled protected mode.
The question is: Is there any other library or method to do the same thing as webdriver does?
I found urllib2 Basic Authentication but I can't figure out how to use it in my case.

**To be clear, Although the script I wrote works well I want to have something similar written with help of urllib2.**

Any help will be appreciated.
Regards
Kamil Jastrzebski

Comment: There is also `.dismiss()` option. Did you use it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Could you expand on that? Or give an example?

Comment: try `driver.get("http://k jastrzebski:pass@my_url/")`

Comment: @KamilJastrzębski See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

use `.accept()` for accepting, and `.dismiss()` for calcelling the `alert` dialog. See below:

```
driver.switch_to.alert.dismiss()
```